# Meaning of this sentence, confused by まで

Tags: meaning

So, Google translate shows this as meaning After 7pm on the day... But doesn't まで mean "until" so why would it be after 7.. And not up until 7?

フロント【内線8番】にて当日19:00まで受付しております

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing the sentence:

> 「フロント【内線{ないせん}8番{ばん}】にて当日{とうじつ}19:00まで受付{うけつけ}しております」

can mean is:

"**We (take your order) until 19:00 on the (same) day at the front desk (Dial #8)**."

Note that I used "take your order" as we have no idea what kind of service this is talking about.

Comment: See, now that's exactly what my initial thought was (it's a couple of pages of food in the information book). And I thought it would be ordering for the restaurant before it opens.  But the Google translate for it threw it as being "from 7" which made me question if it was like room service orders for after the restaurant had opened. But didn't get how it could be from 7 when using "made" thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 0):

> フロント【内線8番】にて当日19:00まで受付しております.

This means util 19:00. From 19:01 , you can`t call.